# Allow post-banned users to edit their removed answers/questions

Tags: feature-request, edits, deleted-questions, post-ban

I've got a question ban on Stack Overflow. Some of my questions with very low votes have been deleted by moderators. I have a list of them. I wanted to improve them and then vote to undelete it, but I got the following message:

> Post is deleted. Unable to edit

I think that banned users should have the possibility to edit their removed posts. The reasons is because nobody sees that post (only those who have a link to it possibly) and some banned users want to improve their deleted posts and be unbanned.

Screenshot :

[image: My ss]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202157/android-google-play-licensing - it's my question. I cannot edit it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817198/search-bots-http-apache-503-service-unavalibe - I also cannot edit it

Comment: @MartijnPieters users can't edit their own deleted question when they have less than 2K. It was introduced only recently in the Roomba stuff that allowed users to see their own deleted questions in the first place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Right, so there is then indeed a missing feature.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm pretty sure that was *meant* to prevent users without full editing privileges from editing deleted posts, because they'd go through without approval. The OP should definitely be able to edit their own deleted posts, as they do have full editing privileges on their own post.

Comment: @animuson in such case it might be a bug... interesting.

Answer (score 3):

In [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1883587#1883587), you said that it was deleted by Community ♦. This is a moderator. [Community auto-deletes some questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/229438) and your question was one of them. I think that the reason that you can't edit it is because a moderator deleted it. You can neither edit, nor undelete it. The only thing you can do is to flag your question for moderator attention to ask to undelete it so you can edit it.

Also if you would delete it yourself, you wouldn't be able to edit it. Here is a screenshot of my deleted Super User question, that I deleted myself:

[image: Deleted question]

Comment: Yeah, but I always should be able to edit my own posts.

Comment: Did you read @animuson comment? : "I'm pretty sure that was meant to prevent users without full editing privileges from editing deleted posts, because they'd go through without approval. The OP should definitely be able to edit their own deleted posts, as they do have full editing privileges on their own post.". I agree with him.

Comment: @Ty221: I don't have a Community deleted question, so I can't check it, but I believe this is the reason.

Comment: so ask Community user to delete one of your questions ;-). Ok, that was only the joke :-) That might be the reason - you're true, but I think users should have possibility to edit all their posts, so I made that request.

Comment: You can see - you are never able to edit your own deleted post